# Importing a Date String from CSV in DD/MM?YY format and converting to DateTime YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Tags: apex, datetime

Been trying to solve this for almost two weeks. I'm importing a date string from a CSV, something like 12/16/16. I want to put this date into the Tasks object Activity Date field, which is Date/Time. However, for the life of me, I can not get any conversion methods I've researched here to work. I always end up with the error of:

> Illegal Assignment from Datetime to Date

Here's the portion of code where I'm trying to address the issue. I'm not a developer by trade, just trying to help some users do some things.

```
tskstoupload = new List<Task>();
for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
{
    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');

    Date ad = Date.valueOf(inputvalues[1]);
    String dt = DateTime.newInstance(ad.year(), ad.month(), ad.day()).format('YYYY-MM-dd');
    Datetime acd = DateTime.valueOf(dt);                     

    Task t = new Task();
    t.WhoId = inputvalues[0];
    t.ActivityDate = acd;
    t.Subject = inputvalues[2];
    t.Priority = inputvalues[3];
    //t.RecordType = inputvalues[4];
    t.Status = inputvalues[4];
    t.Type = inputvalues[5];
    t.Description = inputvalues[6];

    tskstoupload.add(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the timestamp portion of the string. Also, no need to convert from `String` to a `Datetime`, then back again to a `String`, then back again to a `Datetime`. You can do it all in one go.

If you're trying to convert a date-only string into a `Datetime` value, you'll want to use `Datetime.newInstanceGmt` to get the midnight value of that date.

```
Datetime.newInstanceGmt(parsedDate.year(), parsedDate.month(), parsedDate.day()));
```

You can also use a `Time` instance if you prefer that syntax or want to specify a different start time.

```
Datetime.newInstanceGmt(parsedDate, Time.newInstance(12, 0, 0, 0)); //noon
```

The latter strategy is slightly more convenient if you want to one-line the conversion. That in turn would allow you construct the `Task` record using `name=value` pairs without ever needing to cache its `ActivityDate` value. Any time you can construct an `sObject` record with `name=value` pairs, it is significantly faster.

```
Task record = new Task(
    WhoId = inputValues[0],
    ActivityDate = Datetime.newInstanceGmt(
        Date.valueOf(inputValues[1]), Time.newInstance(0,0,0,0)
    ),
    Subject = inputvalues[2]//, etc.
)
```

---

Note that calling `Date.valueOf('12/16/16')` should cause an error:

> System.TypeException: Invalid date: 12/16/16

An input of `2016-12-16` would work, but not `12/16/16`. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) on the `valueOf` method  states:

> **Usage**
>   The specified string should use the standard date format “yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss” in the local time zone.

Instead, if you expect a format of `12/16/16`, use `Date parsedDate = Date.parse(inputValues[0]);`.

Comment: Mind=Blown on that constructing records using name=value pairs. I'm not a developer at all, never even thought about doing that! I got it to work, thank you so much!!!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Glad I could help. :)